# Superscript in a graph label for SAS SGPLOT

Tags: graph, sas, label, superscript

I am creating a graph via SAS SGPLOT and I need to superscript a character in the label.  Is there a simple way to do this?

The graph is a scatterplot with a regression line.  It's a comparison of measurements, basically the same thing measured 2 different ways.  Since the measurement is area, it's in mm squared, which is why I need the superscript.  My code is below.

```
ODS GRAPHICS / RESET IMAGENAME = 'wheal_dig'
IMAGEFMT =TIFF HEIGHT = 90mm WIDTH = 90mm;
ODS LISTING GPATH = 'U:\Wheal'  style=journal2;
proc sgplot data=allx noautolegend;
    reg x=col1 y=col2;
    scatter x=col1 y=col2;
    xaxis label='Digital Area (mm^2)' min=20 max=80 ;
    yaxis label='Manual Area (mm^2)' min=20 max=80 ;

run;
```

Comment: What kind of label? What kind of graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a one off you can copy the character from a [unicode reference table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts).

```
proc sgplot data = sashelp.class;
    scatter x = height y = weight;
    xaxis label = "Superscript copied from unicode table ²";
run;
```

This may not work if your session encoding does not support unicode.

Comment: How do I know if the session encoding supports Unicode?  Apologies, I'm a statistician, not a programmer, so my programming level is quite basic.

Comment: I'd try running the code in my example and seeing if it works, if so copy the character into your code and you should be set. To check your encoding you can run [`&put &sysencoding.;`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002975661.htm) and check the output in the log. My system returns [`utf-8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) which is one of the standard encodings for unicode text.